# OpenSSL version 0.96d or later

Tags: openssl

I need to install

```
openssl
```

for some tests. the version I need is 0.96d or older. I searched for this version but I could not found anything...Anyone an idea how to find it?

Comment: By the way, using OpenSSL 0.9.6d in 2013 is, erm, surprising, at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's quite hard to find : http://www.openssl.org/source/ (most likely you actually need version 0.9.6d or later)